# Why does gradient turns upside down when 0deg is applied?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am learning CSS Gradients, I observed something and I am not able to understand it. *For a  class ~ 'box', I applied the following CSS*

```css
.box{
  width: 50vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

And I got the expected result, however, I then added a - 0deg property (as seen in the code below) the gradient just flipped vertically. Why  did it happen? Shouldn't there be no changes as I wrote 0deg

```css
.box{
  width: 50vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/do-you-really-understand-css-linear-gradients-631d9a895caf), the default angle is "to bottom", i.e. from top to bottom. This is equal to 180 degrees. 0 degrees [is equal to "to top"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()).

So it's simply a case of the default being 180 degrees.

Comment: Whoever thought of that deserves a solid slap.